# Uncaught ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined

Tags: laravel, nodejs, vue.js, npm, vite

Tengo una aplicación de Laravel y vue que no me corre y me suelta este error en la consola. Corro el php y le intento dar a npm install && npm run dev

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
```

No se que podría ser ese error. Las versiones que tengo son

Node v16.15.1
npm v8.11.0
Usa Laravel9, Vue 3 y Vite

Comment: Que versión d enode utilizas?

Comment: @oscarPortillo la versión 16.15.1

Comment: Vale, en principio no sería el problema, te iba a decir de actualizar pero no es eso, seguiré mirando

Comment: sería muy raro que ese error no viniera acompañado de alguna traza que indique en qué parte del código se produce, o al menos en qué archivo

Comment: @ffflabs Me dice que esta en overlay.ts:120

Comment: `globalThis` está pensado para funcionar en browsers, node.js y webworkers. En qué contexto estará evaluando `overlay.ts`? Lo más cercano que encontré es un workaround para declarar `globalThis` igualándolo a `window` cuando no esté definido. Esto se haría en el `index.html` que tienes en la raíz del proyecto. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/7915

Comment: @ffflabs Estuve haciendo pruebas y el error sucede cuando coloco el @vite('resources/js/app.js'), si lo quito y dejo la parte de Laravel, el programa va bien.  El error aparece en esta linea y marca la palabra globalThis, const { HTMLElement = class {} as typeof globalThis.HTMLElement } = globalThis

Comment: @ffflabs Incluso me aparece el error en todos los proyectos que tengo en vue y laravel, en esa computadora. En el resto de computadoras me funcionan perfecto. Capaz no tiene nada que ver, pero justo antes de que me apareciera el error la primera vez, me apareció un mensaje consola, como que el npm había sido actualizado

Comment: Puedes añadir a tu pregunta el contenido de tu archivo `tsconfig.json` **y** la traza completa del error? Dudo que sea cosa de poner  `"lib": [ "ESNext",   "DOM" ]` en las opciones del compilador, pero nada se pierde con intentar. No recuerdo si el script `dev` que aparece en el `package.json` dice sólo `vite` o `tsc && vite`.